# gameViewController background color cannot be changed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, background-color

The App running under spriteKit. Days before, the gameScene was loaded once the gameViewController was loaded. Today, I change its loading action that the gameScene is loaded only when the Start button is clicked, it means the gameScene background color is invisible, I need to set a background color for gameViewController. It's a very very simple task being done many times 
 before, but it sticks on light gray(image below).

Can't gameViewController background color be changed under spriteKit?

Must I change gameScene background color instead?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .green

        // .......
    }

  @IBAciton func loadGameView() {
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            // if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.viewController = self
                scene.size = self.view.frame.size
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)

            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
            view.showsFPS = false
            view.showsNodeCount = false
            view.showsDrawCount = false


        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            scene.viewController = self
            scene.size = self.view.frame.size
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            //ADD THIS
            scene.color = .green
            scene.colorBlendFactor = 1

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)

     }
```

Comment: I know this solution can set the background color, but just don't want to load GameScene before the "Start" button is clicked. Any other solution? Thanks.

Comment: I don't undertand very well your question. If you what change the UIViewController, is exactly as a normal UIViewControlle. But personally I use a SKScene as a menu

Comment: Yes, normally UIViewController's background color can be set by `self.view.backgroundColor`, but this seems not work under SpriteKit.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes. I've also set the background color on storyboard, and I can see the result.